# ConverseJS Filter Contacts

Tags: javascript, xmpp, chat, converse.js

I'm trying to use conversejs library to my web project and i added required js files and make it run. But what i wanted to filter contacts. Once i loaded the page filter box is showing just a moment and disappears. I couldn't find how to enable it. When i use the conversejs on conversejs.org it also has no filter box but in https://conversejs.org/tests.html there is a filter box. This is the box I'm talking about

[image: this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter box only appears if there are more contacts than can be shown in the visible area (causing a scrollbar to appear).